# Enable "high brightness" mode directly from Windows command line

Tags: windows, display, intel-graphics, brightness

When working outdoor with a (e.g. ThinkPad) laptop during a sunny day, we know that brightness 100% can be insufficient:

[image]

Then, an option is to boost Gamma or Brightness or Contrast in the Intel Graphics properties:

[image]

but it's a bit long to go in these settings each time we go indoor / outdoor.

**Question: how to switch these settings directly from command line?** (So that we can automate it with a keyboard shortcut with AutoHotkey)

Question:

Comment: You don't need to do it from CLI for it to be automated with AHK. AHK can click things if you tell it to.

Comment: @Destroy666 Yes, but it's always more error prone if AHK has to open a GUI software, click precicesly at certain places, etc. If updates happen and UI changes, these solutions often won't work anymore. That's why I prefer command-line solution, often much more reliable.

Comment: CLI tools can change too and regular GUI hardware-related apps such as Intel's control panel are very unlikely to have CLI. Quick look for apps changing gamma and I found just this: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/control_my_monitor.html which only works with certain monitors supporting `DDC/CI` standard.

Comment: I bet they are software boost instead of control to the actual screen.

Comment: @Destroy666 Good idea about this Nirsoft tool (his software are always excellent!). Unfortunately, it doesn't work with my ThinkPad integrated monitor.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using WMI.

**CMD**: (`Brightness=XX`) where XX = 1-100

```
wmic /NAMESPACE:\\root\wmi PATH WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods WHERE "Active=TRUE" CALL WmiSetBrightness Brightness=75 Timeout=0
```

**Powershell**: (75 value below is a percentage. Accepts values 1-100.)

```
(Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods).WmiSetBrightness(1,75)
```

Comment: Interesting on its own, but this doesn't change the Intel Graphics parameters like I mentioned: Gamma, Brightness, Contrast.

Comment: Thanks for a generally applicable answer, which I plan to use.